# JAVA JButton in a different class refuses to activate when pressed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, jbutton

I'm failing to understand why my `yankee` and `whiskey` `JButton`s aren't working. Right now I only want them to close the program when `romeo` is greater than 1 and `sierra` is greater than 1.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AlphaMenu extends JFrame /*implements actionPerformed*/
{

    private GraphicsDevice gamma;
    public JButton charlie, zulu, yankee, xray;
    public JFrame beta;
    public JPanel delta, echo, foxtrot, golf, hotel;
    public JTextArea whiskey, victor;
    public BorderLayout uniform;
    public ImageIcon bg;
    public JLabel tango;
    public int sierra, romeo;
    public Integer quebec, papa;
    public ActionEvent oscar;
    public ActionEvent november;

    public AlphaMenu()
    {
        //Initialization of Objects
        charlie = new JButton("EXIT");
        zulu = new JButton("Enter Time");
        yankee = new JButton("Enter Amount of Money");
        xray = new JButton("Calculate");
        sierra = 0;
        romeo = 0;
        quebec = new Integer(0);
        papa = new Integer(0);
        whiskey = new JTextArea(2, 15);
        victor = new JTextArea(2, 15);
        bg = new ImageIcon("background.gif");
        beta = new JFrame();
        delta = new JPanel();
        echo = new JPanel();
        foxtrot = new JPanel();
        golf = new JPanel();
        hotel = new JPanel();
        uniform = new BorderLayout();
        ImageIcon bg = new ImageIcon("background.gif");
        tango = new JLabel("");

        tango.setIcon(bg);

        //Modification of panels
        beta.add(delta, uniform.PAGE_END);
        beta.add(golf, uniform.PAGE_START);
        beta.add(echo, uniform.LINE_START);
        beta.add(foxtrot, uniform.LINE_END);
        beta.add(hotel, uniform.CENTER);

        golf.add(tango);

        //Modification of JButton charlie & adding of JButtons
        charlie.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        delta.add(charlie);
        charlie.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        echo.add(whiskey);
        echo.add(yankee);
        foxtrot.add(victor);
        foxtrot.add(zulu);


        //Modification of JFrame beta
        beta.setUndecorated(true);
        beta.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        beta.setResizable(false);
        beta.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        beta.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void buttonSetup() throws NumberFormatException
    {
        //Modification of JButton yankee & JTextArea whiskey & int sierra
        romeo = quebec.parseInt(whiskey.getText());
        yankee.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 50));
        yankee.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent oscar)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        //Modification of JButton zulu & JTextArea victor & int romeo
        sierra = papa.parseInt(victor.getText());
        zulu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 50));
        zulu.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent november)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new AlphaMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please indent your code - just getting your IDE to format it should do a good job. That will make it *much* easier for us (and you) to understand it. I also suspect you could reduce the amount of code significantly and still demonstrate the problem - see [mcve].

Comment: Side note: even beginners can write non-sloppy code. Actually, that makes your life, our "job"; and the one of your teacher much easier. Code is written ... to be read; so you better focus from day on making the reading part as easy as possible. Or do you think that a mechanic learning his job is allowed to turn his garage in a whole mess?

Comment: I'd also strongly recommend naming your variables according to their purpose, rather than just going through the alphabet...

Comment: It is really difficult to follow your code at the moment, due to the amount of objects you have with alphabet names which mean nothing- as you have to keep referring to the top of your code to actually see what it does. Try and shorten it down, like @JonSkeet said, and I am sure you can find a useful answer then. All the best, and well done for giving a go :)

Comment: whiskey is not a JButton is your code as you stated in the question. The method that establish an yankee is never asigned an actionListener because method 'buttonSetup' is never invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have two JTextArea (JTextField would probably be better) and a button. you want some buttons to execute exit when the text of both textareas is an integer greater than 1.

seems that your `buttonSetup()` function isn't called anywhere.

Anyway, I'd create an ActionListener that reads the texts, converts to integer, tests your condition and executes exit(). This ActionListener should be added to all the buttons you want to perform the action

```
final ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            final int intRomeo = Integer.parseInt(romeo.getText());
            final int intSierra = Integer.parseInt(sierra .getText());

            if (intRomeo > 1 && intSierra > 1) {
                // whatever you want to do
                System.exit(0); 
            }
        } catch (/*NumberFormat*/ Exception e) {
            // ...not integers
        }
    };
}
whiskey.addActionListener(al);
yankee.addActionListener(al);
```

I have to add: the variable names you are using are really bad. Consider choosing something more significative.

Comment: Thank you so much! I rewrote the code using this as the kind of guideline. Also used more accurate variable names. Great response!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, readability...it would probably help the "sloppiness" if you used more appropriate names for your variables, indented different sections of code, and used comments to help describe sections in layman's terms. Maybe "btnExit" and "btnCalculate" would help make things a little easier to navigate.

Moving forward, you also don't have two different classes here, you have one class with several methods. Which is fine but wanted to inform you of that. I think maybe you need to add the buttons to their panels after your action listeners and formatting for each button. I'm just getting into some swing stuff myself and I've noticed moving the .add() functions around in the code has helped when I run into issues like this. Try the following bellow. I indented and used new naming conventions for the comments, but the code uses your convention.

```
//add the pnlEcho to frmBeta
beta.add(echo, uniform.LINE_START);

//format btnYankee
yankee.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 50));

//btnYankee action listener
yankee.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { //default action event
        System.exit(0); //you could use this
        beta.dispose(); //or you could dispose the frame and
                        //do more work after it is gone
    }
});

//add btnYankee to pnlEcho
echo.add(yankee);
```

Comment: Yeah I rewrote the code entirely and it's fifteen times more clean now. Works like a champ. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm failing to understand why my yankee and whiskey JButtons aren't
>   working

The variable wiskey is not JButton type but JTextArea type.

Comment: Yeah my mistake haha. Fixed now anyway.